# Testing controller helper redirect in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Im trying to write a rspec unit test on a helper module

I have `SessionsController` and `SessionsHelper`

Inside `SessionsHelper` i have

```
def redirect_back_or(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  session.delete(:return_to)
end
```

I would like to make a test which would look something like this:

```
describe "redirect_back_or(default)" do
  describe "with stored location" do
    before do
      helper.request.path = users_path
      helper.store_location
    end
    it do 
      expect(helper.redirect_back_or(user_path(@user))).to redirect_to(users_url)
      helper.session[:return_to].should eq(nil) 
    end
  end
end
```

but i get an exception inside the Helper method

```
undefined method `redirect_to' for #<#<Class:0x00000006fc9940>:0x00000005322620>
# ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:34:in `redirect_back_or'
# ./spec/helpers/sessions_helper_spec.rb:99:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no direct fix for your problem here.

The thing is that a rails helper is not a good fit for the kind of functionality you want to implement.

The files in `app/helpers` is meant for VIEW helpers. So methods that you are going to use in the templates or for rendering.

The kind of functionality you are implementing is on the controller level. Good places in rails would be to put it in the `ApplicationController` or a file in `app/controllers/concerns`, like they are funky and hip nowadays.

You can then test it through a request or controller spec.

Comment: Thanks!

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-sessions_controller

I used this guide for help. I guess it is a bit outdated. I also confirmed your statement that app/helper is for views. I thought they are on the controller level. I will move the methods to a more suitable place.

Comment: I did put in the `ApplicationController` and all the controller inherits from it.